# How to the get of a path without file:\\ being at the beginning

Tags: c#

I am working on a c# project and I am trying to get the current path of where my executable is running from. However, the method that I am using is adding `file:\\` to the beginning i.e. `file:\\C:\\users\\user\\Project\\Debug` all I want the string to be is `C:\\users\\user\\Project\\Debug` but I can't find a way to do this.

Below is the code I am using

```
string basePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string basePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var basePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```